# Multidimensional Repeating Data Control

Tags: asp.net

Excuse my title if it's confusing, but I don't know how else to describe this, except in the long explanation below:

I would like to create a multidimensional, templated, data bound, repeating ASP.NET control, with paging and sorting.  I.e. You specify how many columns and rows per page, so items are displayed across and down, e.g.

[dataItem1][dataItem2]
[dataItem3][dataItem4]

The Repeater and DataList controls don't offer paging, and the DataGrid, with paging, is restricted to one item per row.  I would appreciate suggestions on how to go about this.  I am limited to .NET 2.0 for this endevour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a new ListView control in 3.5 that can be displayed the way you describe.

If you tweak the 'tiled' or 'single row' views you can probably do what you like and it supports paging out of the box.

Comment: I'm currently restricted to 2.0, but I'd love to have a look at that control.